# Why Google does not show complete meta description

Tags: google-search, search-results, meta-description

I am working on a website, I have done it on-page nearly complete. I am using 160 words description.

In SERP I see `meta` `description` half from 160 words and half from website page.

Answer (score 2):

Google uses its own algorithm to decide how to display the snippet in their results. If your meta description is being completely or partially ignored, it's likely because Google has determined it isn't representative of the page content so it's doing a mix and match.